# Error catching in dynamically generated assembly

Tags: c#, dynamic, try-catch

I'm having trouble with an application I've written, it's basically creating dynamically generated assemblies based on code input by the user.
It compiles and runs fine, but for some reason, sometimes when an Exception occurs in that compiled assembly, it crashes the main program even though everything is thoroughly coated in try/catch blocks.

I add try/catch blocks to surround the user's code in the generated assembly, and also try/catch around the Invocation of the assembly in my app:

```
StringBuilder verificationErrors = new StringBuilder();
argz[0] = "hello!";
argz[1] = verificationErrors;
object loResult = null;
try
{
   loResult = loObject.GetType().InvokeMember("doThis", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, loObject, argz);
}
catch (Exception p)
{
   MessageBox.Show(p.Message);
}
```

It looks like the error is being thrown outside the scope of my app, so it doesn't know how to catch it or something to that effect... any ideas?

Comment: ...and how are you generating the assembly? CodeDom? Reflection.Emit? Something else?

Comment: Did you try debugging it by putting a breakpoint at `loResult = .....` to check if the control reaches that line or not?

Comment: The error is a SeleniumException, this is an app to be able to compile Selenium c# scripts and run them on the fly.  The SeleniumException occurs occasionally (when an element in the DOM is not found, etc), and it isn't being caught.  I'm using CodeDom to generate the assembly, passing in params and GenerateInMemory =false.  I have tried debugging, but it will only debug the app, not the generated assembly.  I put a debug point at loResult and it reaches it, it just errors because something in that function is erroring, and it can't catch the error.

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this? I have a similar problem. I am wondering if the reason you are unable to catch the error is because its occurring inside a new thread created within the invoked member? Certainly thats the case in my situation.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that the invocation of p.Message is throwing an exception. One would presume that we're using the default Message property, but it could be a custom exception that overrides the Message property.

I would wrap the code in the catch block with a further try...catch, and if it throws an error, just say "An unexpected error occurred", and log whatever you can about it.

Comment: It's not the p.Message, I tried just putting an empty catch and it's still not catching the error, it errors on the line where I'm calling the function inside the generated assembly.  I know exactly why it's erroring, it's just not preventable because the users are allowed to put their own code in - so I need it to be catchable.  There are try/catch blocks around the user's code, and the call to the generated assembly function, but the app still crashes saying unhandled exception.

Comment: You might try putting in a specific catch block for SeleniumExceptions. Without knowing the specifics of the internals of the SeleniumException object, you can't know for sure how it's going to behave. I mean, as .net programmers, we're trained that "catch(Exception e)" is supposed to catch everything, but the reality is that that exception, and the code associated with it, contains to be operated upon by the CLR. Also, be sure and view the call stack when you debug the exception (Debug...WIndows...Call Stack). That may give you a clue as to what's going on.

Comment: Last piece of advice, when you can't debug, instrument. Put log entries pre and post the user compiled code and see what that tells you.

Answer (score 0):

If you run the program in debug and instruct Visual Studio to break when an exception is thrown, you should be able to inspect the stack trace and determine which method is throwing the exception.

1. Go to Debug / Exceptions...
2. Check the box in front of "Common Language Runtime Exceptions", in column "Thrown"
3. Click "OK"
4. Run the program in debug mode

Comment: This doesn't provide much help, because it can't debug the dynamically generated assembly, just the app that is controlling the assembly.

Comment: And I know exactly where the error is occuring, there's just nothing I can do to prevent it since the user is the one inputting the C# code into the dynamically created assembly.  It's not a compilation error, it's a run-time error that occurs only sometimes, but it is not being caught even though it's directly inside a try/catch.

Comment: The invocation call.. loResult = loObject.GetType().InvokeMember("doThis", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, loObject, argz);